# Moodle template editing

Tags: php, templates, moodle

I am a Drupal developer now learning Moodle.

I have a need to programmatically insert HTML on Math based quiz pages. So, each math question should display my custom HTML.

Doing the above in Drupal simply involved copying, renaming and editing template.php files and you are then able to customize the display of specific pages.

How can I do the same in Moodle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moodle doesn't use template files. It uses "output renderers" instead. Overview: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Output_renderers

Overriding a renderer: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Overriding_a_renderer